# How to open a folder with more than a single word in its name on Terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: terminal

I have a folder in my documents called "page xyz by abc" at the moment I have been able to reach */users/shahz/documents>* now when I write cd page xyz by abc I get an error "no such file or directory"

I know it is an extremely basic question but for some reason I am failing at this miserably. Please help!

Comment: Don't forget that you can drag and drop a folder/file in the terminal to get its path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotation marks:

```
cd "page xyz by abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the backslash :

```
/users/shahz/documents/page\ xyz\ by\ abc
```